# Best way to check if access_key matches NEAR account

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm building a user authentication solution matching near accounts to **my own** generated access tokens. I want to verify in my node.js backend (using Nearlib?) if a `near access key` (stored in local storage in browser) matches the near account provided. This is to prove that the request is actually sent by the account owner.

So if I have:

```
accountID: "myAccount",
near_access_token: "ed25519:{...}"
```

I'm also assuming that the correct `near access token` to use here is under `nearlib:keystore:klopt:default`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to verify in my node.js backend (using Nearlib?) if a near access key (stored in local storage in browser) matches the near account provided.

You should be able to get list of access keys for given account using `account.getAccessKeys()` call https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearlib/blob/master/src.ts/account.ts#L202

Then you can check whether key pair in key store has same public key.

> This is to prove that the request is actually sent by the account owner.

If you want to prove that request is sent by the account owner – you need to verify signature though.

See e.g. this code in account helper micro-service:
https://github.com/nearprotocol/near-contract-helper/blob/19ac6ce05a0d44f0e389c85b30bc2b6a9190caac/app.js#L97

In that case `securityCode` had to be signed by account (when setting up account recovery). In your case instead of signing `securityCode` you want to sign the request.

You should be able to sign request using `Signer.signMessage` API https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearlib/blob/master/src.ts/signer.ts#L38